# Semantics of class vs ID in reusable templates

Tags: html, semantics

I'm working on an online store. I've learned a little PHP and so I'm using a single template file with some conditional includes and such rather than building separate product pages (no database yet though, still learning!).

So I have `section`s that only exist once per instance of the template (ie once per page) such as `section id="product_image"`. Normally that would be identified with an `id`. But on a template which is reused a bunch of times do you think `class` would be more semantically appropriate? (yes I know there's no functional/technical need to switch to `class`)

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 0):

An `id` is singular. There can be only one of the same ID on the page, and an element may only have one ID attribute.

So if your component gets reused, the ID *must* be different between reuses (Perhaps some sort of database primary key, or something similar).

A class name describes your elements semantically, i.e. this section is a what? widget? calendar? featured articles? That's what a class name is for.

---

Personally, I always use class names, and only use IDs if I want the link-scroll functionality. Classes, are everything IDs are, but more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

the `id` and `class` attributes may be used for structure and functionality, but not semantic meaning, although readability in markup is a great aim.

To infuse your markup with meaning, use [semantic elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element), and [structured data](http://schema.org/docs/schemas.html).

The [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) is a great resource.